Simulation of actuators (Piezoelectric) in Simetrix
I was going through this Simetrix user manual to find out whether we can simulate actuators in Simetrix.
Unfortunately, I couldn't find any.
I am using this High Voltage Driver IC to simulate this actuator.
Should we create a model like this for an actuator? If some, any guidance on how to do it?

This program appears to be a circuit simulator. If you construct a circuit model of the piezo device then yes, you can simulate it with this program.
